# Is there any way to execute commands in order without callbacks in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to connect **MongoDB** and find some documents.

The fact is, i will use this client (**mongo**) across all modules. It's mean it is **shared**.

I made a module and made a `connect()` function. Also i have `find(params)` function. When I execute `connect()` outside of class and then `find()`, `find()` gets executed before mongo connects to db. This is because of nature of `NodeJS`. Means `async`.

But how can i await connection get established and then execute my queries?

**Python** has asyncio but still i can connect and then execute my queries without callbacks... I use NodeJS just because of SocketIO but right now i am really thinking if im doing wrong by choosing NodeJS and switch to Python. Could anyone give me something so i can write better code? Any documentation to read? Or is there any trick for this cases?

For example, I query database (postgresql) and this query returns a data. I have to process this data but i can't do it in order. I use callbacks again. If I follow NodeJS rules, It looks like `callback in a callback in a callback in a callback.....` goes like this. More basically, lets say a request has been made to NodeJS and i have to query 3 different SQL texts. Each of them depends on before. I have to implement 3 queries and callbacks inside of each callback.

Am I understand this wrong? Since 7 hours I'm driven to crazy.

I like the Async feature. Really. But what should I follow for this cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques available to reduce callbacks extending horizontally.

#### [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

```
async.series([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
]);
```

#### [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
doStuff
    .then(function() { ... })
    .then(function() { ... })
```

#### manual logical breaks

```
doStuff(function(err, callback) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    ...
    callback(null, nextThing);
});

function nextThing(err, callback) {
    ...
}
```

---

Specific to your db driver confusion, I would imagine you should have code structured something like this:

```
var mydb;

client.connect('mydb', function(err, db)) {
    mydb = db;
    httpserver.listen();
}

// ...

function restMethod(request, response) {
   mydb.query(..., function(err, result) {
       ...
   }
}
```

i.e. connection objects, http routing, etc should all be stored in module-level variables or other objects, rather that having your entire application relying on callback parameters.

Comment: But,I declare Mongo connection at top of any code. In this example, I have to put all of my rest code inside of a callback function. Is it wise?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mongo module you are using, but if you actually have to do that then the module has a fantastically bad design. If should return you a client object that you can store for later use.

Comment: Thanks! Promises solved my problem. Now i can continue to code with love :)

Answer (score 2):

There is  a **npm sync** module also. which is used for synchronize the process of executing the query.

When you want to run parallel queries in synchronous way then node restrict to do that because it never wait for response.
and sync module is much perfect for that kind of solution.

Sample code

```
/*require sync module*/
var Sync = require('sync');
    app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
      story.find().exec(function(err,data){
        var sync_function_data = find_user.sync(null, {name: "sanjeev"});
          res.send({story:data,user:sync_function_data});
        });
    });


    /*****sync function defined here *******/
    function find_user(req_json, callback) {
        process.nextTick(function () {

            users.find(req_json,function (err,data)
            {
                if (!err) {
                    callback(null, data);
                } else {
                    callback(null, err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

reference link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync